# NiFi generateTableFetch processor adds milli seconds in the state value when using timestamp in maximum-value column field as an incremental fetch

Tags: timestamp, state, teradata, apache-nifi

I am using generateTableFetch processor to fetch data from a teradata db table where timestamp is used for incremental fetch in maximum-value columns. The format for this timestamp is timestamp(0) but it stores the state by adding milli second value to it.

For example, my timestamp is in the DB as 2020-01-01 13:30:32 and when the generateTableFetch porcessor stores the state, it is 2020-01-01 13:30:32.0 ,so when next time it queries to get incremental data it gives an error invalid time stamp any help or suggestion on how to resolve this?

Also, I tried this (see below screenshot) as well and getting error code 3706, stating " expected something between ')' and the word '{column name containing timestamp}' ",  which I am not able to resolve.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHgVS.jpg)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and was fix by converting the column into timestamp. You have to CAST(columnname as timestamp). You may also want to read this https://downloads.teradata.com/forum/database/get-the-date-and-time-in-yyyy-mm-dd-000000-format-in-teradata-sql

Comment: Please elaborate.